# call from view controller method rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ba is scaffold generated class I created it like this :

```
rails generate scaffold Ba src:string descr:string title:string
```

I have view `home.html.erb`
There I have

```
<%= render 'layouts/bas' %>
```

I made a `_bas.html.erb` file and placed it in layouts folder. It has this code:

```
  <%  Ba.find_each do |ba| %> *CODE* <% end %>
```

And it works well and fine.
But I want to place my find method in controller cause it might be bigger than just find all.
So in my `StaticPagesController` I created

```
def bas
  @bas = Ba.find_each
end
```

But I get the error the bas is nill. 
My controller code

```
  def home
  end

  def help
  end
  def about
  end
  def contact
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign `@bas` in corresponding controller action and it will be available in view

If you really need to call a method on controller from view - use `helper_method`:

```
helper_method :bas
def bas
  #code...
end
```

Comment: I told in my question that  I defined method bas in my staticpages controller and it gave me an error. So if I define this helper method how to call it from a view?

Comment: @user2950593 the point is in declaring it as a helper so it can be called from view